# How is this string concatenation evaluated?

Tags: c#, string, immutability

I know how the following code be evaluated:

```
string s = "Hello";
s += " My ";
s += " World";
```

It basically do 3 evaluation (please correct me if wrong):

1. Assign a string "Hello" to variable s
2. Create another string "Hello My " and assign to variable s
3. Create another string "Hello My World" and assign to variable s

Which basically leaving `"Hello"` and `"Hello My "` weakly referenced and can be GC-ed.

What I don't know, how they evaluate the following code?

`string s = "Hello" + " My " + " World";`

Does it evaluate the same?

**Update**

The answer give me another question. How about the following code?

`string s = "Hello" + EvaluateJoin() + " World";`

where

```
private string EvaluateJoin(){ return " My "; }
```

Comment: string concatenation like this will only get a problem in a loop, because the compiler can't optimize it.

Comment: @Scordo I would rephrase that a bit: will only get a problem in a loop, *because then you are creating lots and lots of intermediate strings*. It isn't because of compiler optimization: it can't optimize the first example even if it isn't inside a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the first bit, "yes, basically", up to

> Which basically leaving "Hello" and "Hello My " weakly referenced and can be GC-ed.

No, they aren't referenced *at all* any more.

Edit: Henk correctly notes that `"Hello"` and `" My "`, however, are interned (due to `ldstr`) - so will not be collected. The combined `"Hello My "`, however, is **not** interned and will be collectable.

For the second example: because those are all constants in a single expression, the compiler combines the constant at compile time; that represents a single interned string `"Hello My World"`, which you can see in the IL.

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    string s = "Hello";
    s += " My ";
    s += " World";
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);

    s = "Hello" + " My " + " World";
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

compiles to:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr "Hello"
    L_0005: ldstr " My "
    L_000a: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string)
    L_000f: ldstr " World"
    L_0014: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string)
    L_0019: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_001e: ldstr "Hello My  World"
    L_0023: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0028: ret 
}
```

Here you can clearly see both the `Concat`s for the first example, and the single pre-combined string for the second.

Comment: Your answer give me another question. May you also answer the update?

Comment: @Fendy the edit will behave a lot like the first example, because the compiler does not attempt to inline methods - thus it will not see that it always returns a constant expression. The number of times that this optimization will *actually* be possible is vanishingly small.

Answer (score 2):

> Which basically leaving "Hello" and "Hello My " weakly referenced and can be GC-ed.

No, strings are interned and constant strings will never be GC-ed. So only `"Hello My "` is collectable.

> Does it evaluate the same?

The end result certainly is the same. There are no evaluation issues (timing, dependencies) here.

Comment: `"Hello My "` is not interned, and is collectable; only literals via `ldstr` are *automatically* interned (although strings can also be manually interned)

Comment: Right, the intermediate would be collectable.